# How to replacement "<%=" from jsp to jsf2 page

Tags: jsp, jsf-2, xhtml

I have JSP page with this code :

```
<f:verbatim><%=printPassedParam(request)%></f:verbatim>
```

`printPassedParam` returns `String` type. (it return some html tags)
I wanna to migrate to JSF2, how could I replace `<%=` in xhtml page ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you need a primer in basic JSF. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) first

Answer (score 0):

I did it just by using "h:outputText" like this. It's working :)

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{page.beanName.printPassedParam()}"/>
```

Comment: Even I found better way
just put ${beanName.printPassedParam()} on that place